# Calling a php function unsing jquery goes wrong

Tags: php, jquery, function, post

- I want to call a php function but it doesn't seem to work correctly.
  Here is my setup:

**1. Setup works**

file.js:

```
refresh("file.php");

function refresh(php_file_path){
        var file_path = php_file_path;
        $.post( file_path, {"action": "bla" }, 
            function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
        },"json");
    }
```

file.php:

```
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
      $data = "Test";
      echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

output in console:

"Test"

This works!

- when I change the file.php so that a function is called in the if-statement, I get nothing back.

**2. Setup doesn't work**

file.js:

```
refresh("file.php");

function refresh(php_file_path){
        var file_path = php_file_path;
        $.post( file_path, {"action": "bla" }, 
            function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
        },"json");
    }
```

file.php:

```
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
      $data = myfunc();
      echo json_encode($data);
    }

    function myfunc(){
      echo "Testfunc";
    }
```

output in console:

nothing

Is there anybody who get's the mistake? Thanks!

Comment: `myfunc()` echoes the value instead of returning it to the calling function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign `myFunc` to a variable if it doesn't `return` something

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
  $data = myfunc();
  echo json_encode($data);
}

function myfunc(){
  return "Testfunc";
}
```